# Sitecore 9.3 Identity Server Redirects to 404

Tags: configuration, sitecore-install-framework, identity-server, setup

I configured a content management server with Identity server. Accessing the CM server takes me to the Identity server correctly, but after logging it redirects me to https://cm-sitecore93.test.com/identity/signin which returns a 404.

After this whenever I try to access Sitecore shell it takes me to this page.

Am I missing any configurations?

Comment: You need to set this correctly to your cm site <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>http://pocsite1.sc</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>http://pocsite2.sc</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
</AllowedCorsOrigins> on IdentityServer side -> look here -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17224/2056

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this issue.  After restarting identity server, the following error appeared in the logs:

System.Exception: Error processing block: Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.ConfigureSitecore ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: Certificate cannot be obtained with defined parameters.

This lead me to investigate the thumbprint in the sitecore.IdentityServer.host.xml file. When I went to see if that SSL cert was still valid, I realized that it no longer existed. Someone must have removed it so I updated the thumbprint to a valid SSL cert, restarted the identity server and I was back up and running.

Note: The above error only showed AFTER restarting the identity server.

Answer (score 0):

go to your Identity server instance and open the xml file `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` in `Sitecore Identity server\Config\production` folder and add your CM url to allowed AllowedCorsOrigins like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <CertificateThumbprint>Certificate Thumbprint</CertificateThumbprint>
      <CertificateStoreLocation>LocalMachine</CertificateStoreLocation>
      <CertificateStoreName>My</CertificateStoreName>
      <SitecoreMembershipOptions>
        <ConnectionString>Core DB connection string</ConnectionString>
      </SitecoreMembershipOptions>
      <AccountOptions>
        <PasswordRecoveryUrl>https://cm-sitecore93.test.com/sitecore/login?rc=1</PasswordRecoveryUrl>
      </AccountOptions>
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://cm-sitecore93.test.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>
        <PasswordClient>
          <ClientSecrets>
            <ClientSecret1>Your Client Secret</ClientSecret1>
          </ClientSecrets>
        </PasswordClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Copy the above config and update the following 
Certificate Thumb print
Core DB connection string 
Client Secret

This should resolve your issue. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check either the **Network Dev Chrome** tab or **Sitecore logs**. Experienced with the **404** redirecting on the **Sitecore 9.3** with **extranet** user logging. It was the ***Sitecore Licence issue*** - here the [Sitecore hotfix](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/646268)

Probably you got the same one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, ID takes me back to correct CM domain, but got a 404 on the POST to `/identity/signin`.

In my case I had scaled the CM environment to multiple instances but did not turn on `Sticky Session` as per [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/scaling-and-configuring-content-management.html) document from Sitecore: "Out-proc session state management is not officially supported. We recommend that you use in-process session state and sticky sessions.". Enabling this fixed the issue.